# local variable not accessed & 'this' context enforcement

Tags: javascript

i have the following piece of code that is giving me trouble working [question(s) after code]

```
var LIB = function(){};

(function(){
var JSExpert = function(lname){
    if(!(this instanceof arguments.callee)){
        return new JSExpert(lname);
    }

    this.fname = "Later ";
    this.name = this.fname + lname;
};

JSExpert.prototype = {
    setFname: function(fname){
        this.fname = fname;
        return this; //for chaining
    },

    getName: function(){
        alert("javascript expert name is " + this.name);
    }
};

LIB.Expert = JSExpert;
return;

    window.JSExpert = JSExpert;
})();
```

Now here come the test code

```
LIB.Expert("Edwads").setFname("Dean").getName();
```

Now when you try the code the setFname() method which is supposed to change "Later " in the constructor by "Dean" isn't doing it, why is that????

Second question: we're using 'this' inside JSExpert. how can one be sure the context of 'this' isn't bound later to the context of 'LIB' and stay enforced to that of 'JSExpert' and thus 'LIB.Expert' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Change

```
setFname: function(fname){
    this.fname = fname;
    return this; //for chaining
},
```

to

```
setFname: function(fname){
        this.name = this.name.slice(this.fname.length);
        this.name = fname + ' ' + this.name;
    this.fname = fname + ' ';
    return this; //for chaining
},
```

2) In the contructor function you check `this` type:

```
var JSExpert = function(lname){
    //If not an instance of this class creates a new object of this class and return it
    if(!(this instanceof arguments.callee)){
        return new JSExpert(lname);
    }

    this.fname = "Later ";
    this.name = this.fname + lname;
};
```

In the other functions you can do something like `if (!(this instanceof JSExpert)) throw new Error('');`, throwing an error is the best you can do here, this is a drawnback in using the prototype.

Comment: i already did the instance check. i was hoping there was a better way to enforce context instead of throwing errors in 50 methods :) thanks for the setFname().

Answer (score 0):

Because this:

```
return;

window.JSExpert = JSExpert;
```

is not correct, should be:

```
window.JSExpert = JSExpert;
```

and

```
getName: function(){
    alert("javascript expert name is " + this.name);
}
```

should be:

```
getName: function(){
    alert("javascript expert name is " + this.fname + this.lname);
}
```

and `lname` needs to be a property like fname. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eFnV3/)

---

```
var LIB = function() {};

(function() {
    var JSExpert = function(lname) {
        if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
            return new JSExpert(lname);
        }
        this.lname = lname;
        this.fname = "Later ";
        this.name = this.fname + lname;
    };

    JSExpert.prototype = {
        setFname: function(fname) {
            this.fname = fname;
            return this; //for chaining
        },

        getName: function() {
            alert("javascript expert name is " + this.fname + ' ' + this.name);
        }
    };

    LIB.Expert = JSExpert;

    //window.JSExpert = JSExpert;
})();

LIB.Expert("Edwads").setFname("Dean").getName();
```

Comment: i'm not using the JSExpert object on the window object, so it doesn't affect the cod behavior. Yes two local variable work, still why isn't 'this.name' being updated? i don't wanna have a bunch of variables all over when they are all related and can be combined into one variable in the constructor.

Comment: @Eric I don't thing you are understanding what's happening here. The `this.name` variable is set to the value of `this.fname + lname`. At the time that that is defined, the values of the other variables are retrieved, a string concat is done, and that value is stored. Not sure why you assume that changing `this.fname` will somehow affect the string value of `this.name`